# how do i get the previous selected drop down item using javascript?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

i have a drop down menu, on clicking any item from the list i want to get the previously selected item. Is it possible using javascript?

Comment: The Question is unclear, if i select A the next time when i choose B should i get A; and the 3rd time when i choose C ill get B?

Comment: yes, first time i select A and then B, i should get A next time when i select C i should get B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
<script>
var selHistory =[];
var sel; 
window.onload=function() {
  sel = document.getElementById('selID');
  sel.onchange=function() {
    selHistory[selHistory.length]=sel.selectedIndex;
  }
  sel.onchange(); // save the current option
}
function getPrev() {
  return (selHistory.length < 1) ? "no previous":sel.options[selHistory[selHistory.length-2]].value
}
</script>
```

or perhaps

`<select onChange="var prevSel=(this.selectedIndex>0) ? this.options[this.selectedIndex-1].value:'nothing previous'">`

Comment: i think this solution will work when i have selected A then B then C. Will it work when i have selected B then A then C?

Comment: It should work regardless. It will add the last selection to the array when you change the select and return whatever the previous was

Answer (score 0):

You can just save selected item into some var and read from it when next item will be selected.

Comment: That is some great advice the asker can use some time when he understands some more javascript ;) But I would not call it an answer...

Comment: You just missing difference between giving an advice and performing somebody's else job )

Comment: I do not consider my 10 lines of code as doing a job. However I do see your advice as a comment rather than an answer...